# Is there a way to implement Interaction Tests with only stories.mdx files in storybook

Tags: javascript, angular, storybook

I'm trying to implement interaction tests but I only have stories.mdx files. When I looked at the docs it seemed like only tsx or ts files were used so I'm not sure if what I'm asking is doable.

I tried adding somewhat of a play proprierty in my Story tag but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.